How to encrypt and decrypt password using Java Spring Security
Hope you are doing great,
I'm finding difficult to implement the encode of password on client side and decode on server
I'm able to encode de password before it get submitted on client side using Js, and I created a Filter and added it the configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation.
The function in the filter I created just take the request and decode the password then set the password attribute of request again.

The password does decode properly but it is not dispatched to the other Filters.
Filter :
 @Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    WebAuthenticationDetails webAuthenticationDetails = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();

    String ip = webAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress();
    System.err.println("???? " + ip);
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    System.out.println("-- authenticate : "+password);

    if (password.equals("admin")) {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUserName(name);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication, encoder().encode(password), getAuthorities(Arrays.asList(user.getRole())));
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password test");

     }
    }
WebSecurithyConfig :
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // add Gregory Goufan
    http.addFilterBefore(passwordDecryptionFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    
    http.addFilter(passwordDecryptionFilter);
    
    http
        //.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    http
        //.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/login")).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login*", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/pages/**", "/img/**", "/fonts/**", "/plugins/**", "/jrxml/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    Cookie sameSiteCookie = new Cookie("SameSite", "None");
    
    http.addFilterBefore(new SamSiteAndCSPFilter(sameSiteCookie) ,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    http.addFilterBefore(totpAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/tokenValidation").hasAuthority(Authorities.TOTP_AUTH_AUTHORITY);
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").failureUrl("/login?error=true").failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler).successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);

    http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).invalidSessionUrl("/login").maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and()
            .sessionFixation().none();

    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/raya/login?logSucc=true").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();
            

    }

Can you show me the filter and security config.
